# Why does the new Function() return this output?

Tags: javascript, function

I was reading Chapter 4: Functions() of the book Javascript Enlightenment by Cody Lindley.

http://jsfiddle.net/4a860dkg/

I was playing around with functions and wanted to know why in the fiddle `addNumbersA` returns anonymous(num1, num2, /**/) rather than returning a function()

Can anyone tell me why does this happen?

**EDIT:** 
1. What I want to ask is that why doesn't logging `addNumbersA` return me a `function()` as it must do.
2. When I use `typeof(addNumbersA)`, I get a `function` and not a `function()` - whereas `addNumbersB` returns `function()`.

Apologies if i'm not clear enough.

Comment: Doesn't the book tell you that?

Comment: I don't get your question but using the standard console would probably be more enlightening (remove firebug and type F12)

Comment: @JoakimM no the book doesn't tell me unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason console.log(addNumbersA); returns:

```
function anonymous(num1,num2
/**/) {
return num1 + num2
}
```

Is because its a functional expression.  The function keyword, when used as an expression, can create a function value.  A function value can do all the things that other values can do—you can use it in arbitrary expressions, not just call it. It is possible to store a function value in a new place, pass it as an argument to a function, and so on.

Similarly, console.log(addNumbersB); returns:

```
function (num1, num2) {
    return num1 + num2;
}
```

You can test this out in chrome dev tools, perhaps some inspectors/js repls have different notations of shortcutting, such that you may not get EXACT output (ie. just get 'function()' in Firebug).

Answer (score 0):

Function is a constructor for function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

When you define a function as an instance of Function constructor, it is not compiled but stored as a runtime string.  That's why it shows up as a function definition and not as a function object.

They will function the same except because it is compiled at the time of execution, it only has the global closure and has no knowledge of the local closure except for its own local variables.

Answer (score -1):

```
console.log(addNumbersB); // logs function() correct!
```

This will not run the function, which your are expecting.

**This does:**

```
console.log(addNumbersB(2,2)); // logs 4 correct!
```

The above returns 4 because we call the function and pass the two numbers which are then added by the function;

The first example you give is a method rarely used for normal day to day coding, it creates a function from a string that represents valid code.

Comment: Not the downvoted, but for starters, you have a syntax error in your answer.

Comment: I wasm't asking this. I was asking about why doesn't it return me function() as the type of object.